# Perfion web api: check whether a feature is remote or not

Tags: xml, api, product, wep

I am newbie on Perfion System.

How can I check whether a feature is remote? My current query looks like that:

```
<Query>
  <Select languages='EN'>
    <Feature id='**'  />
  </Select>
  <From id ='Product'/>
  <Where>
    <Clause id='ID' operator='=' value='2458' />
  </Where>
</Query>
```

and I get this result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data totalExecutionTime="00:00:00.3232753">
    <Features>
        <ItemFeature1 id="45445" language="EN" caption="" captionAlternative="" unit="EUR" help="" abbr="" group=""  topViewGroup="" topViewGroupOrder="0" viewOrder="5485" form="Simple" dataType="String" />
        <ItemFeature2 id="4544" language="EN" caption="" captionAlternative="" unit="EUR" help="" abbr="" group="" topViewGroup="" topViewGroupOrder="0" viewOrder="5485" form="Simple" dataType="Number" />
        <ItemFeature3 id="4545" language="EN" caption="" captionAlternative="" unit="EUR" help="" abbr="" group="" topViewGroup="" topViewGroupOrder="0" viewOrder="5485" form="Simple" dataType="String" />
        <ImageFeature1 id="7878" language="EN" caption="" captionAlternative="" unit="EUR" help="" abbr="" group="" topViewGroup="" topViewGroupOrder="0" viewOrder="5485" form="Complexe" dataType="image" />
    </Features>
    <Product id="1000" parentId="0" brand="Normal" order="1569" createdDate="2014-01-30T14:29:00" modifiedDate="2016-01-14T08:23:00">
        <Value seq="0" modifiedDate="2014-01-30T14:29:53.073">Sample 520</Value>
        <ItemFeature1 modifiedDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00">0</ItemFeature1>
        <ItemFeature2 modifiedDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00">TEST44</ItemFeature2>
        <ItemFeature3 modifiedDate="0001-01-01T00:00:00">Abcs </ItemFeature3>
    </Product>
</Data>
```

How could I check weather ItemFeature1 is a remote feature?

How can I get all the Features name even if there is no product with the ID 2458?

Comment: I think following [these trivial rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) could make your posts much better with only a little work.

Answer (score 0):

This information can be discovered in the UI of the Perfion application.  Navigate to the "Features" ribbon.  Right-click on the feature that you are trying to identify, click Edit.  If the "remote" section is defined with a database and query, it is a remote feature.  All of the feature ids are listed in the UI.

Comment: Since the OP is talking about the api, he probably needs to check it programmatically.